# Make K5150 to work on raspbian buster

Tags: usb, raspbian-buster

Trying to connect to internet through K5150 usb modem on raspbian buster(last build from raspberry, September).

On windows it is connecting when it is plugged in.

Here is trying to connect but not receiving tx and it is the stand by icon: ↑↓ one arrow blue, one arrow grey.

When tried manual:

```
sudo ip link set wwan0 down
```

and:

```
sudo ip link set wwan0 up
sleep 65
ifconfig wwan0
route -n
```

It is:

```
wwan0: flags=4291<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>
    ...
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 37  bytes 7004 (6.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
mbim-network /dev/cdc-wdm0 start
```

It is connected.

```
...
Network started successfully
Saving state at /tmp/mbim-network-state-cdc-wdm0... (TRID: 7)
```

Comment: I assume this works for you. Would you please accept the answer.

Comment: It is a timer. Still have to wait. "You can accept your own answer in 9 minutes"